# Why is the Android support library not added to my .apk?

Tags: android, ant, build, android-ndk

I am attempting to build the [Android port of Hedgewars](https://code.google.com/p/hedgewars/wiki/HedgeroidGuide) on Windows, using make/ant on the console. After some trial and error I managed to complete the entire build process, but the built application will not start. logcat reveals the reason to be that the classes from the [Android Support library](http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html) are missing.

However, the library (android-support-v13.jar) is present in the "libs" directory of the android project, and it is clearly used during the build since removing it will cause errors when compiling the java sources. I checked the classes.dex file where the library classes should be added (as far as I understand), and they do not appear to be there.

So, what might be the reason that the support library is not included in the .apk? Other (native) libraries in libs/armeabi are being included. The build is performed using ant, with a build.xml that basically just sets up the variables `sdk.dir` and `target` (android-13), then imports `${sdk.dir}/tools/ant/build.xml`.

To clarify, *I know how to get a working build with eclipse*. The question is why the normal ant build fails to add the library, and how that can be fixed.

Here is the build.xml in the project directory (without the comments):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="MainActivity" default="help">
    <loadproperties srcFile="local.properties" />
    <property file="ant.properties" />
    <loadproperties srcFile="project.properties" />
    <fail
            message="sdk.dir is missing. Make sure to generate local.properties using 'android update project'"
            unless="sdk.dir"
    />
    <import file="${sdk.dir}/tools/ant/build.xml" />
</project>
```

local.properties defines sdk.dir, project.properties defines target, ant.properties is empty.

Update: Oh of course, I updated everything to the latest versions (ndk8, sdk19), pulled from the Hedgewars repository for good measure, and now it works. No idea what exactly made the difference, unfortunately. I guess that means the best candidate for the bounty is NickT, but he didn't make it a proper answer. Suggestions in the comments.

Comment: What device are you testing on? If you are testing on a device that's API is < 13 you will get these crashes. Try using the support library v4 instead

Comment: The device I am testing on is a Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1N with Android 3.2, so it should be API level 13.

Comment: Two questions: Are you using SDK Tools r17 or later? Do you override any targets in your build.xml?

Comment: @NickT, I was using r17, but let me update to the latest everything and try again. The build.xml does not seem to override any target, I'll paste its content into the question (sans comments) since it's pretty short.

Comment: @NickT, since your comment was the one that led me to the right solution and I don't want to waste the bounty, I can award it to you if you post an answer of some kind, like "make sure everything is the lastest version". Of course, everything WAS the latest verison when I originally asked the question... :P

Comment: Did updating to the latest SDK tools solved your problem? I have the similar problem. I will update to SDK 18 if it worked for you.

Comment: @dcanh121: Yes, this is what fixed it for me - read the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that this was a bug in the Android SDK. The release notes of r18 say:

> Fixed Ant issues where some jar libraries in the libs/ folder are not
>   picked up in some cases.

Since updating from r17 to r19 fixed the problem for me, this was very likely the cause of the problem. Thanks to NickT whose comment pointed me in the right direction, even if it was just a clarification question.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, try updating to the very latest version of SDK tools

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse, go to project properties and select the `Order and export` tab. Check the required libraries and clean build.

Hope that helps!

Comment: As I said, I know how to get it to work in eclipse. It's the console/ant build I'm interested in here. I'll edit the question to make that more clear, but it's already in there.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you have some conflicts with v4/v13?

> Special case for android-support-v4.jar and android-support-v13.jar.
>
> We make a special case for these two libraries because -v13 contains a full version of -v4 >inside. If both are found, then only -v13 will be used.
>
> Note that we can’t guarantee that the version of -v4 inside -v13 is the same as version used >by the other libraries. We recommend that when you update your project with a newer version >of the support library, you update all of your projects at the same time, whether they use -> v4 or -v13.

[[source]](http://tools.android.com/recent/dealingwithdependenciesinandroidprojects)

Comment: That is a different problem. The jar file is found by javac and compiling succeeds for me. Plus, if you read my question through you'd know that the library is already in the libs directory.

Comment: Updated my answer. My mistake, jumped the gun.